# How do I model an RF coil in SPICE?

Tags: rf, transformer, inductor, antenna, resonance

I am trying to model a transmit/receive RF coil in SPICE - specifically, a coil that one might use on an NMR spectrometer.

Put simply, the RF coil detects an EMF per Faraday's Law of Induction, by which a current is induced in the RF coil. This may then be read in by an ADC.

For instance, consider an RF coil tuned to 128 MHz, the resonant frequency of <sup>1</sup>H (proton) at typical clinical MRI field strengths of 3 Tesla. My understanding is that the RF coil could be modeled in SPICE as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXBrgL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

where V1 is the EMF voltage, R1 and R2 are the network impedance, C1 is the tuning capacitor, and RF_COIL is a transformer consisting of 1:1 coupled inductors at 1.5nH. The primary winding (left) represents the EMF and is driven by V1, and the secondary winding (right) is the physical RF coil in which the current is induced. I am assuming that I do not need the tuning capacitance on the left inductor's network - is this an incorrect assumption?

Is this a reasonable way to model the RF coil/antenna in a SPICE frontend such as LTspice? My goal is to be able to determine relatively accurate current and voltage at a given frequency.

**Edit**
Regarding some links allegedly not working in the comments below, I am adding the citations here for interested readers:

Gruber B, Froeling M, Leiner T, Klomp DWJ. RF coils: A practical guide for nonphysicists. J Magn Reson Imaging. 2018 Jun 13;48(3):590–604. doi: 10.1002/jmri.26187. Epub ahead of print. PMID: 29897651; PMCID: PMC6175221.

Buxton, R. (2009). Basic physics of magnetism and NMR. In Introduction to Functional Magnetic Resonance Imaging: Principles and Techniques (pp. 121-146). Cambridge: Cambridge University Press. doi:10.1017/CBO9780511605505.010

Comment: Is the coil \$^1 \$H or 1.5 nH? Check an earlier sentence for the anomaly. Current is not induced in the coil at all; voltage is induced and, current may flow as a result of that induced voltage. **This may then be read in by a DAC** <-- that makes no sense.

Comment: 1H a.k.a. proton specifies the frequency to which the spectrometer is tuned. DAC vs. ADC was simply a typo and is corrected. Regarding the induction of a current, that particular phrasing seemed acceptable to me, see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6175221/ and https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/introduction-to-functional-magnetic-resonance-imaging/basic-physics-of-magnetism-and-nmr/3A34EEC26EDB092FB724709D0BB1353C for just a couple of academic examples.

Comment: "Page not available" for the first link and "error 404" for the 2nd link. Voltage is induced.

Comment: Michael Faraday himself refers to the phenomenon as an induction of current. Faraday Michael. 1832 V. Experimental researches in electricity. Phil. Trans. R. Soc.122: 125–162.
http://doi.org/10.1098/rstl.1832.0006

Comment: Eddy currents (rather than the load current associated with an induced voltage as per your question) are probably just about acceptable (to me at least) because there is a direct induction formula. For the rest of Faraday's work on induction; just look up the formulas and see how they exclusively refer to induced voltages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coupling factor to NMR spins is extraordinarily low (~ppm range IIRC, at least at typical concentrations; if you're doing pure water, maybe as much as fractional percents?).  As a source, it might as well not be there, and you are essentially measuring noise from the coil's own resistance.

As such, the equivalent circuit will be more or less the RLC series or parallel equivalent of the RF_COIL secondary, C1, and their internal losses, and no source or primary; and maximum power transfer will be had by matching that loss resistance to R2 through whatever means are suitable.

Coupling from the drive coil will be far stronger: by several orders of magnitude, even if carefully balanced to mostly cancel out its contribution (if this shall be a crossed-field / precession based measurement).  An input limiter or blanking switch is usually required for this reason.

Comment: So basically, just the RLC circuit of the receiver coil with a voltage source driving it should be a sufficient model?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

MR receiver coils use preamplifiers near the receive element. They have input impedance with usually 50 Ohm. The noise visible on the MR image is the thermal noise, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

U_noise_rms = sqrt(4 * k * T * R * BW)

k=boltzman constant

T=body temperature, say 310 °K

R=50 Ohm

BW=128pixel * 1000 Hz/px (e.g. 128x128 image matrix; BW setting in MR sequence for Siemens systems is given in Hz/Px)

-> U_noise_rms = 331 nV

If your image snr is e.g. 100, then your signal voltage is 100 times U_noise_rms.
Voltage, induced by MR spins in the receive resonator (usually loops) depends on the impedance of your loop (there is an impedance matching network in between). Loop impedance depends on several factors, but my guess is, that the induced voltage differs by max one order of magnitude from the above values.